# data structures organizing numbers and words python

Tags: python

Winnipeg, MB[4988,9715]564473
1611 686 1833 1446 550 1279

I'm trying to organize my code into 4 different data structures.  One is the name and state(Winnipeg, MB), the second is the location ([4988,9715]), the third is population (564473) and the 4th is mileage (1611 686 1833 1446 550 1279).  The line on the file is shown above.

here is my code for each line (I also have a some print statements to check my code):

```
import re
#writing a program that stores data into its appropriate data structure

#this function parses through each line to find the name

def parseName(s):
    #setting up variables as lists, strings, and index
    city = []
    index = 0
    cityList = []
    cityCordinate= []
    population = []
    milage = []
    #spliting characters
    listSplit = re.split('\W+', s)
    print listSplit
    #checking to see if first element in list is a letter
    if listSplit[0].isalpha:
        print "alpha"
        cityCordinate = listSplit[2:4]
        cityCordinateFinal =  map(int, cityCordinate)
        population.append(listSplit[4])
        print cityCordinateFinal
        print populationFinal
        #running through line to see if it is a word
        for i in listSplit:
            print i 
            if i.isalpha():
                city.append(i)

        #joining city name and state together and appending to new list        
        cityList.append(", ".join(city))
        print cityList
    #checks milage
    elif listSplit[0].isdigit():
        for i in listSplit:
            milage.append(i)
        print milage
```

For some reason if I were to plug in parseName("1611 686 1833 1446 550 1279") it would print

```
['1611', '686', '1833', '1446', '550', '1279']
alpha
[1833, 1446]
['550']
1611
686
1833
1446
550
1279
['']
```

it is entering the first if statement which somehow is true?  Could someone explain to me how this is possible when the first element of the split list is a digit, not a letter(is.alpha).  It works for my first line if I were to type in parseName("Winnipeg, MB[4988,9715]564473"). it would return:

```
alpha
[4988, 9715]
['564473']
Winnipeg
MB
4988
9715
564473
['Winnipeg, MB']
```

which it is doing correctly.  Could someone point out the mistake?
And I do have another question,  When I start having multiple lines of milage like this:

1958 1452 1484 1799 921 1703 1043 1096 1226 1005 2026 2152 1330 1287 471 204
1174 1540 1507 1593 1308 1427 1415 1227 1132 1892 2082 887 1338

Will I have a problem with storing each milage to each city/coordinate/population?
There is also misspelling in my code please forgive me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling isalpha, you're just referencing the method (which since it exists, returns as True).

You need parantheses to call the method, e.g.:

```
if listSplit[0].isalpha():
```

For more detail, see this output from the command line interpreter:

```
>>> ''.isalpha
<built-in method isalpha of str object at 0x7f6448b02508>
>>> ''.isalpha()
False
```

Comment: by the way, how I'm setting up to my code pass through each line, would I have a problem in the future with how it is organized? @ernie